# Run SQL requests generated by some script

Tags: sql-server-2008, delete, scripting

I'm using this script to delete data from all the tables in my database. It generates `DELETE` statements in proper order, each request in one row :

```
DECLARE @schema_name sysname;

DECLARE @table_name sysname;

DECLARE @constraint_name sysname;

DECLARE @constraint_object_id int;

DECLARE @referenced_object_name sysname;

DECLARE @is_disabled bit;

DECLARE @is_not_for_replication bit;

DECLARE @is_not_trusted bit;

DECLARE @delete_referential_action tinyint;

DECLARE @update_referential_action tinyint;

DECLARE @tsql nvarchar(4000);

DECLARE @tsql2 nvarchar(4000);

DECLARE @fkCol sysname;

DECLARE @pkCol sysname;

DECLARE @col1 bit;

DECLARE @action char(6) = 'DROP';  

DECLARE @referenced_schema_name sysname;



DECLARE FKcursor CURSOR FOR

     select OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)

         , OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), name, OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)

         , object_id

         , is_disabled, is_not_for_replication, is_not_trusted

         , delete_referential_action, update_referential_action, OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id)

    from sys.foreign_keys

    order by 1,2;

OPEN FKcursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM FKcursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name, @constraint_name

    , @referenced_object_name, @constraint_object_id

    , @is_disabled, @is_not_for_replication, @is_not_trusted

    , @delete_referential_action, @update_referential_action, @referenced_schema_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN



      IF @action <> 'CREATE'

        SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE '

                  + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)

                  + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(@constraint_name) + ';';

    ELSE

        BEGIN

        SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE '

                  + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)

                  + CASE @is_not_trusted

                        WHEN 0 THEN ' WITH CHECK '

                        ELSE ' WITH NOCHECK '

                    END

                  + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(@constraint_name)

                  + ' FOREIGN KEY (';

        SET @tsql2 = '';

        DECLARE ColumnCursor CURSOR FOR

            select COL_NAME(fk.parent_object_id, fkc.parent_column_id)

                 , COL_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id, fkc.referenced_column_id)

            from sys.foreign_keys fk

            inner join sys.foreign_key_columns fkc

            on fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id

            where fkc.constraint_object_id = @constraint_object_id

            order by fkc.constraint_column_id;

        OPEN ColumnCursor;

        SET @col1 = 1;

        FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @fkCol, @pkCol;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

        BEGIN

            IF (@col1 = 1)

                SET @col1 = 0;

            ELSE

            BEGIN

                SET @tsql = @tsql + ',';

                SET @tsql2 = @tsql2 + ',';

            END;

            SET @tsql = @tsql + QUOTENAME(@fkCol);

            SET @tsql2 = @tsql2 + QUOTENAME(@pkCol);

            FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @fkCol, @pkCol;

        END;

        CLOSE ColumnCursor;

        DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor;

       SET @tsql = @tsql + ' ) REFERENCES ' + QUOTENAME(@referenced_schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@referenced_object_name)

                  + ' (' + @tsql2 + ')';

        SET @tsql = @tsql

                  + ' ON UPDATE ' + CASE @update_referential_action

                                        WHEN 0 THEN 'NO ACTION '

                                        WHEN 1 THEN 'CASCADE '

                                        WHEN 2 THEN 'SET NULL '

                                        ELSE 'SET DEFAULT '

                                    END

                  + ' ON DELETE ' + CASE @delete_referential_action

                                        WHEN 0 THEN 'NO ACTION '

                                        WHEN 1 THEN 'CASCADE '

                                        WHEN 2 THEN 'SET NULL '

                                        ELSE 'SET DEFAULT '

                                    END

                  + CASE @is_not_for_replication

                        WHEN 1 THEN ' NOT FOR REPLICATION '

                        ELSE ''

                    END

                  + ';';

        END;

    PRINT @tsql;

    IF @action = 'CREATE'

        BEGIN

        SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE '

                  + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)

                  + CASE @is_disabled

                        WHEN 0 THEN ' CHECK '

                        ELSE ' NOCHECK '

                    END

                  + 'CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(@constraint_name)

                  + ';';

        PRINT @tsql;

        END;

    FETCH NEXT FROM FKcursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name, @constraint_name

        , @referenced_object_name, @constraint_object_id

        , @is_disabled, @is_not_for_replication, @is_not_trusted

        , @delete_referential_action, @update_referential_action, @referenced_schema_name;

END;

CLOSE FKcursor;

DEALLOCATE FKcursor;
```

After I copy those statements and run them.
Is there anyway to generante these statements and execute them in just one step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of issuing `PRINT @tsql;`, you can issue `EXEC( @tsql );`, if I understand what you're asking.

If so, I would suggest declaring a preview parameter ( something like `DECLARE @Preview BIT = 1;` ) and then use an `IF` to either print or execute.

```
IF ( @Preview = 1 )
BEGIN
    PRINT @tsql;
END ELSE BEGIN
    EXEC( @tsql );
END;
```

Comment: it did the job ! Thank you very much @Avarkx